# Can Codeigniter be hosted on Parse

Tags: codeigniter, parse-platform

now that Parse has announcement their support for PHP I was wondering if anyone has jumped on the wagon and integrated codeigniter on parse servers (not just as a backend service). I mean hosting codeigniter and all related files on parse. Can this be done?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Parse is a framework for rapid development allowing you to code and not worry about architecture details. Meaning, you'll use Parse inside your codeigniter application to do cool stuff like save data objects, users, geo information etc. You can not however run codeigniter from parse's servers.

Comment: That is also what I thought until I read this: https://parse.com/docs/hosting_guide